# How to extract internet email headers from outlook emails?

Tags: python, email, outlook

i am actually trying to extract the following details from outlook emails.
1. From
2. To
3. Reply - To
4. Return Path
5. X-Agari Original Sender
6. X-Agari Original Receiver
7. X-Originating IP
I have tried Python with exchangelib, win32com.client but could not extract the details.
Can some one help me please?

Comment: Using what API? Outlook Object Model through COM?

Comment: Anything is fine for me. I have tried with COM but i could not get the details. Below is the code which i wrote using exchangelib.

The below code is actually iterating over all the items in  a mail box but i want this to run only when an email arrives into inbox.

from exchangelib import *
config = Configuration(server='XXXXXXX',
credentials=Credentials(username='XXXXX', password='XXXXXX'),
auth_type=NTLM
 )
account = Account(primary_smtp_address='XXXXXX', config=config,access_type=DELEGATE)
print(account.inbox.all())
for item in account.inbox.all():
        print(item)

Comment: That is not the Outlook Object Model. Is Outlook installed on the machine where your code is running?

Comment: Yes Outlook is installed. So far, for COM objects, i have achieved this.
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
class Handler_Class(object):
    def OnNewMailEx(self, receivedItemsIDs):
        for ID in receivedItemsIDs.split(","): 
            mailItem = outlook.Session.GetItemFromID(ID)
            print("Subj: " + mailItem.Subject)
            print("To: "+mailItem.To)
            print("From :"+str(mailItem.Sender))
outlook = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("Outlook.Application", Handler_Class)
pythoncom.PumpMessages()

Comment: But that does not extract Internet headers the previous one does. But previous one is too slow to do this task as we might get thousands of emails at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HeaderParser module. This allows you to parse through html in python to find headlines and headers and such.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html